# Max amount of Text(_:) in VStack?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a VStack with eight `Text(_:)` views in it. When I try to add another Xcode gives me the following error: Extra argument in call. I have done the "clean build folder",  restarted Xcode and my computer. Nothing helps.

This must be a bug, right? There can't be a limit to how many textviews that can be contained in a VStack? At least not as low as eight.

I'm running the latest versions of everything on a Mini M1.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: The more Views defined in a single body, the more inefficient it is to track changes etc. so they made a hard cap of 10. It's best to make many small Views.